# Drag n drop files to Document Libraries in Quick Launch bar?

Tags: 2013, drag-and-drop

In a Document Library with files and folders in it, I can drag 'n' drop files to the folders from the browser. However, I'm unable to drag 'n' drop files to other Document Libraries on the Quick Launch bar (i.e., the links on the left hand side). I'm led to believe that this should be possible.

Any pointers as to why I can't drag 'n' drop files to Document Library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" feature enabled on a Site Collection, drag 'n' drop to Document Libraries on the Quick Launch bar doesn't work anymore.

Disabling the SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure feature (from Site Settings -> Site Collection Features) makes the drag n drop work again.